# custom sort NSFetchController in ios

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am using NSFetchResultController to fetch objects from core data, I can sort it by using sort descriptor but I want to show some custom list in my UICollectionView, with following sequence,

```
first 2 object of "type = 1"
next 1 object of "type = 2"
next 2 object of "type = 1"
next 1 object of "type = 3"
next 2 object of "type = 1"
```

So, can I use any NSPredicate to sort like above sequence where sequence is property of my entity class ?

currently if I used sort descriptor then I can get first of all type =1 then type =2 and then type =3, 
or is there any other way or logic to get expected output ?

can we query differently and add the result into single fetchController ?
or can we change the ordering in fetchResultController ?

Comment: Can you explain what sorting you want a little more? I can't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: yes, I know we can sort with parameters, but I want to change the ordering, i.e. we can say it is mixed sorting, In my collection view first i want to show only 2 object of "type=1" and then some other object say "type=2" and again now want to show elements of "type=1" so on, means mixed objects but of constant sequence.